# If the probability of getting $12$ is $0.4$ and the remaining numbers have uniform distribution of $0.6,$ which number would you pick?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The following is an interview question.

> Given $2$ dice. You and your opponent pick a number represents the sum of $2$ dice. If the probability of getting $12$ is $0.4$ and the remaining numbers have uniform distribution of $0.6,$ which number would you pick?

I think we should pick a number with the highest probability of occurrence. Without the unfairness assumption (that is, dice are fair), we should pick $7$ as it has the highest probability $\frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}.$

But with the additional assumption, I do not know which number has the highest occurrence probability.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150930/brain-teaser-on-simple-probability-question?rq=1) for a roughly similar question.  The probabilities are the same, but it is one $12$ sided die and it makes clear what the criterion is for picking a number.

Answer (score 4):

The question tells you the probability of $12$ is $0.4$ and implies that the probability of any other number is $\frac {0.6}{10}=0.06$ so you should pick $12$.  This is on the assumption that the dice are numbered from $1$ to $6$ as we are used to.  It also implies that the dice are not independent, because you can't make the other probabilities uniform if they are.  Probably you are just expected to note this and say the wording is designed to have us make unwarranted assumptions.